# Notepad++: Reducing multiple line breaks to single

Tags: regex, text, notepad++, line-breaks

My text document has multiple line breaks at random places. Want to use **Notepad++** to reduce any multiple line breaks to a single line break. How can I accomplish that?

I am on the lines of using `\n` in extended *Find/replace* mode but can't quite get it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a regular expression S&R:

```
(?:\r\n){2,}
```

or

```
\R{2,}
```

in the *Find what* field and

```
\r\n
```

in the *Replace with* field. You may adjust the replacement pattern as per your needs.

[image]

Comment: this is selecting even single line breaks

Comment: Do you have just `\n`s or `\r\n`s?

Comment: I have `[\r\n]+` as u suggested. even with `[\r\n]{2,}` it is selecting single line breaks

Comment: In case you have `CRLF` line endings, this should now work: `(?>(?:\r\n){2,})`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `\R` if you want to deal with any kind of line break (ie. `\r` or `\n` or `\r\n`):

Find what: `(\R)+`
Replace with: `$1`

This will replace multiple line breaks (of any kind) with a single one.

Comment: Problem is that it also selects single line breaks which I want to leave intact

Comment: @Kashif: In fact they are selected, but NOT removed.

Comment: This is a better answer.